# Preventing user to enter more then 3 numbers before decimal point in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, decimal

In PHP textfield: Prevent the user from entering more then 3 numbers before decimal point
for example:

if user enter 123.12 its acceptable,
if user enter 12.12 its also acceptable,
but if user enter 1234.12 its not acceptable.

Just check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/S6uky/

---

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Val 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="validate" name="val1" maxlength="5"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Val 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="validate" name="val2" maxlength="5" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Val 3</label>
        <input type="text" class="validate" name="val3" maxlength="5" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
  $('.validate').blur(function(){
      var reg=/^[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[\.]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$/g;
      if($(this).val().match(reg)==null)
            alert('Invalid input!');
                                          });});
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Try this regex: "\d{0,3}[.]\d+|^\d{0,3}$"

Answer (score 1):

```
function isAccept(number){
  return number.indexOf('.') < 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/9cmSF/1/)**

```
    $(function(){
      $('.validate').blur(function(){
      var reg=/^[0-9]{0,3}[.][0-9]{0,2}$/g;
      console.log($(this).val().match(reg));
      if($(this).val().match(reg)==null)
            alert('Invalid input!');
      else
           alert('valid input!');          
                                          });});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.test()` this way:

```
$(function () {
  $('.validate').blur(function () {
      var reg = /^[0-9]{0,3}[\.]{1}[0-9]{0,2}$/g; //<---updated this
      if (!reg.test(this.value)) {
          alert('Invalid input!');
          $(this).focus();
          return false;
      }
  });
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/24RLg/1/)

Another way is make a global function and use it as a callback:

```
function isValidInput() {
  var reg = /^[0-9]{0,3}[\.]{1}[0-9]{0,2}$/g;
  if (!reg.test(this.value)) {
      alert('Invalid input!');
      $(this).focus();
      return false;
  }
}

$(function () {
   $('.validate').blur(isValidInput);
});
```

[**Another fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/24RLg/2/)